# Sql query to extract data containing a specific text with inserted 0 in any position

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a variable

```
$sub='MCS1';
```

Now I want to run a query to extract data from the column `Subject` say that contains the following elements

0MCS1, MCS01, MCS001, MCS10, MCS001, MCS010

I have tried using `like` but could not reach the goal as the position of 0 or 00 can be anywhere in the string.

Please give me a clue.

Answer (score 1):

A clue of mine would be to use REGEXP: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

You would have to dissect your base string into parts, though. E.g. `$prefix = 'MCS'; $suffix = '1';`

In your case, the regexp could look like: `'.*'.$prefix.'{1}[0]*['.$suffix.']{1}.*'`

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE Subject REGEXP '.*MCS{1}[0]*[1]{1}.*';
```